# Show that R is isomorphic to a direct product of local rings.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Suppose $R$ is a ring containing algebraically closed field $k$, and $R$ is finite dimensional over $k$. Show that $R$ is isomorphic to a direct product of local rings.

Please give me a sketch or a hint to this problem.

Comment: You can check Fulton - Algebraic Curves Chapter 2.9 for a detailed proof. It is freely available on the internet.

Comment: Is this true: if R finite dimensional over k, then $R=k[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]/I$ for some ideal $I$.

Comment: @PetersonAuthor Yes that is true. Pick a basis $e_1,\ldots, e_n$ for $R$ over $k$.  $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]\to R$ given by $X_i\mapsto e_i$ is surjective, so modding out by the kernel establishes the isomorphism you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Maybe that's an isomorphism Thm?